# how to click on nav menu list items using selenium web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

Somebody please suggest me how can i click on menu in selenium web driver. I am trying to find out by css selector and directly by id,link text but its not work:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("nav > ul a#user")).click();
```

Help is highly appreciated. Below is the code:

```
 <nav>
    <ul style="">
    <li class="">
    <a id="dashboard" title="Dashboard" href="ajax/dashboard.html">
    </li>
    <li>
    <a id="controlpanel" href="ajax/controlpanel.html">
    </li>
    <li class="active">
    <a id="user" href="ajax/user.html">
    </li>
    <li class="open">
    <a id="audcon" title="client" href="#">
     <b class="collapse-sign">
    </a>
    <ul style="display: block;">
    <li>
    <a id="client" href="ajax/client.html">
    </li>
    <li>
    <a id="stores" href="ajax/location.html">
    </li>
    <li>
    <a id="sub_category" href="ajax/auditgroup.html">
    </li>
    <li>
    <li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a id="quescon" href="#">
    <ul>
    </li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <a id="help" href="guidelines.html">
    </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Following

```
driver.findElement(By.id("user")).click();
```

**OR**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='active']")).click();
```

Comment: Its not working . No Such Element Exception... It is not locating the object